# How to change permission upload file image?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am new to PHP, I am doing the image upload function, the problem I have is that although successfully uploaded I don't have access to that image, is there any solution for this is not ?

my code:

```
public static function uploadImage($image){
        try {
            $rand = rand(1, 1000);
            $target_save =  "./Public/upload/".$rand.Helpers::slug($image['name']);
            move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $target_save);
            chmod($target_save, 777);
            return Helpers::getUrlPage().trim($target_save, "./");
        } catch (Exception $e){
            return Helpers::getPathPublic('admin')."images/no_image.webp";
        }
    }
```

notification I get when opening pictures on my computer

```
It looks like you don t have permission to view this file check the permissions and try again
```

I tried running my application on xampp completely without this problem, but if I use MAMP PRO I will have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the permissions of your file afterwards?
It seems like you are using an incorrect chmod `mode`
It is stated in the [chmod documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.chmod.php), that you should use octal values as secong argument.
An example:
`chmod($target_save, 0777);`

Also make sure the reading user has the correct permissions to read the file.